# How do I eliminate a duplicated nested SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have a query along the lines of:

```
Select 
    ItemCount, 
    (Select Sum(ItemCount) Where <5-item conditional>) as ItemTotal,
    JobSize,
    (Select Sum(JobSize) Where <SAME 5-item conditional>) as JobTotal
...
```

And duplicating the test sticks in my craw. Is there any way around this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you reading everything from a single table three times? Are you reading from two tables (one for the main query and another for the subqueries)? Are you reading from three different tables? Any solution to your question depends a lot on the answer. A little more information can go a long way.

Comment: And does the code you presented actually run on that DBMS?  Because the subqueries do not appear to be valid SQL (even accounting for insertion of a valid conditional).  Each requires a `FROM` clause: the outer query *cannot* be assumed as a row source, because the outer rows can be filtered on the subquery results.  For that reason, I had assumed your code to be schematic, but some of your comments imply that you expect it to work as-is with only insertion of the proper conditionals.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I simplified it down to the essential details.  The real thing is 2.5k with over 20 parameters.  The query produces the correct results, it's just I'm normally very aggressive about pulling out duplicated work like this and I don't see how to do it here.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, I think you have simplified it down to something that does not accurately reflect what the query does.  Discussion about which rows are filtered, etc. needs to be informed by the relevant `FROM` clauses, or at least representations of them that show how the real ones are related to each other.  We cannot address your concerns in that direction based on what you have posted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WITH statement.
For example:

```
WITH template_name AS (
  SELECT ItemCount, JobSize...
  FROM <your_table>
  WHERE <5-item conditional>
)
```

And then your query can be transformed to:

```
Select 
ItemCount, 
(Select Sum(ItemCount) FROM template_name) as ItemTotal,
JobSize,
(Select Sum(JobSize) FROM template_name) as JobTotal
```

Comment: This eliminates writing the text twice but I already made a string in my code that does the same thing.  The server is still going to have to execute it twice (and it's the most expensive part of the query, it hits another table.)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that all the per-item subqueries use the same `WHERE` predicate, you can perform them all in the same query and join the one result row back to the base table:

```
SELECT 
  base.ItemCount, 
  agg.ItemTotal,
  base.JobSize,
  agg.JobTotal
FROM
  base
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
      Sum(ItemCount) AS ItemTotal,
      Sum(JobSize) AS JobTotal
    FROM base
    WHERE <5-item conditional>
  ) agg
```

That gives you just one subquery instead of two (or more), which is even better than just pre-filtering the rows.  If you want to apply the same conditional also to the (original) outer query, then you can combine that with the `WITH` approach described in the other answer to filter once for all.

**Update**: here is an example of combining a joined aggregate query with a temporary table generated via a `WITH` clause:

```
WITH target_rows AS (
  SELECT ItemCount, JobSize...
  FROM base
  WHERE <5-item conditional>
)
SELECT 
  target_rows.ItemCount, 
  agg.ItemTotal,
  target_rows.JobSize,
  agg.JobTotal
FROM
  target_rows
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
      Sum(ItemCount) AS ItemTotal,
      Sum(JobSize) AS JobTotal
    FROM target_rows
  ) agg
<optional additional filter predicate>
```

As I initially wrote, this applies the `<5-item conditional>` filter once overall, so it is the most efficient if the result rows are supposed to be filtered on the same criteria as the aggregate query(-ies).  You can add a `WHERE` clause to the outer query to further filter the results.

Alternatively, you can adapt that to apply a different filter in the `WITH` clause, and still apply `<5-item-conditional>` in the subquery.  That's a reasonable way to limit the rows considered by the subquery to just those considered by the outer query.

Comment: I do agree this would avoid executing the offending code twice but it certainly seems to me that this cure is worse than the disease--it seems to me it executes the test on every line in the database, not merely those selected in the first query.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, your original code does that, too.  At least twice.  Or if the query optimizer misses it, perhaps many, many times.  The rows examined by any subquery are determined only by that subquery's `FROM` clause; they are not inherently restricted by the outer query.  If your outer query is subject to the same condition, then do as I already suggested: combine the join approach with a `WITH` table.  I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: I don't understand.  My code only tries to calculate the sums for lines matching the outer conditional.  It seems to me that your version calculates the sums for everything in the database.  Is there any way to see what the query optimizer does?  I might be hunting something that's irrelevant.